# How to javascript remove duplicate item

Tags: javascript

I use javascript to get response data from firebase result. Now I have list item respone like

```
Luxury
Sedan
MPV
Hatchback
SUV
Luxury
Luxury
Luxury
Luxury
```

Now I want to display this respone on HTML, but no have duplicate more name luxury.

I try to use

```
var uniqueNames = [];
            $.each(names, function(i, el){
                if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
            });
```

With `names` is my list respone, but it not a array. What I wrong in here, please help me to find a way to fix it

### Thanks a lot

you can follow data this image
[link image response here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3H7o.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Comment: If your response data is not an array, which type is it?

Comment: type is a string

Answer (score 0):

[Time to switch to Set from ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

> Set objects are collections of values. You can iterate through the elements of a set in insertion order. A value in the Set may only occur once; it is unique in the Set's collection

```js
const uniq = new Set(['Luxury',
  'Sedan',
  'MPV',
  'Hatchback',
  'SUV',
  'Luxury',
  'Luxury',
  'Luxury',
  'Luxury'
])

for (let item of uniq.keys()) console.log(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I not sure whats the problem on your situation, maybe you can provide the response data from database and the end result you get. We might figure out wheres the problem located.

But here is an alternative way to do it.

```
var uniqueNames = names.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
     return index == self.indexOf(elem);
})
```

Hope it help.

Comment: you can follow data response on my description, I just updated, thanks

Comment: for now my data is string, it not array, so I can't use your code suggestion

Comment: sorry, got confused, is the response from db is 1 by 1, instead of a list? It doesn't look like a list's response from the screenshot you provide